# Getting values from a just created array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this function that creates an array of values:

```
function getPostInfo($query, $fields, $type, $limit, $since, $until, $lang, $stopwords, $identifier) {
$url = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.spaces($query).'&fields='.$fields.'&limit='.$limit.'&until='.$until);
 $j = json_decode($url);
  foreach($j->data as $v) {
  if ($v->type == $type) {
        $author_id = $v->from->id;
        $original_id = $v->id;
        $post_url = getPostUrl($original_id, $author_id);
        //$description = stopWords($v->message);
        $description = $v->message;
        $pub_date = $v->created_time;
        $post[] = array(
        'author_id' => $author_id, 
        'orginal_id' => $original_id, 
        'post_url' => $post_url, 
        'descritpion' => $description, 
        'pub_date' => $pub_date
        );
    }
}   
    return $post;
}
```

When I call this function like this:

```
$post = getPostInfo($query, $fields, $type, $limit, $since, $until, $lang, $stopwords, $identifier);
echo var_dump($post);
```

The array returns correctly.

But If I try to search for a specific value of the array like this:

```
echo var_dump($post['author_id']);
```

it always returns NULL.

What is wrong in my code?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: @DamienPirsy what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that comment. Anyway, I meant: if you do `$post = getPostInfo(...); var_dump($post); var_dump($post['author_id']);` do you see the index gets unset? Or are you just checking the index _without_ having first created the array?

Comment: Did you forget to call the getPostInfo function before the second var_dump?

Answer (score 3):

I believe if you change

```
$post[] = array(
```

to

```
$post = array(
```

it should fix the issue. 
Can you display the result of your `var_dump($post)`?

Comment: If I do so it will return only one time, and not all the times it should as the foreach suggests....

Comment: Ok, you will then need to index the first array when you make your call then. var_dump($post[0]['author_id']);

Answer (score 0):

The assignment in the function is wrong. You need to use this code (strip the [] parentesys)

```
    $post = array(
    'author_id' => $author_id, 
    'orginal_id' => $original_id, 
    'post_url' => $post_url, 
    'descritpion' => $description, 
    'pub_date' => $pub_date
    );
```

or access the index you need by

```
 $post[0]['author_id']
```

In this situation you should rely on [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) or [var_export](http://php.net/var_export) to investigate on how your data structure is layed down. I prefer the second one as is output is similar to
the code needed to obtain the data and it is easier to find errors.

In the manual, you will see that var_dump returns void and if you try to echo its result you will not obtain what expected

```
echo var_dump($post['author_id']);
```

strip the echo and you will get fine with you output (use var_export or ob_start if you need to get a string with the output).

**EDIT**

As in the comment, the $post variable is an array of arrays, the above notes are still valid as you need to access the various `author_id` index prefixing the index of the array containing it. If you need to get all the id of the authors in a place then you can resort to array map:

```
$authors = array_map(function($x){return $x['author_id'];},$post);
```

If you where was trying to obtains something else you should better explain what the expected result was.

Comment: If I do so it will return only one time, and not all the times it should as the foreach suggests....

Comment: I tried every of your suggestions. It always returns NULL.. :(

Comment: Sorry, I was misdirected by the instruction to get the author_id.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this really fun and easy.

```
function getPostInfo($query, $fields, $type, $limit, $since, $until, $lang, $stopwords, $identifier) {
//your code
    }
}   
    return (object)$post;
}
```

then when you access your returned object it's just

```
$post->author_id;
```

this is just for fun but it works well. Converts an array into a standard object. :)

ok let's get serious ;)

Initialize the array before the foreach statement (*$posts = array()*), then assign the variables to the array keys (*$post['key'] = $value*) then assign each set of array keys to the array (*$posts[] = $post*). I hope this helps.

```
function getPostInfo($query, $fields, $type, $limit, $since, $until, $lang, $stopwords, $identifier) {
$url = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.spaces($query).'&fields='.$fields.'&limit='.$limit.'&until='.$until);
 $j = json_decode($url);
 $posts = array(); //initialize array here
  foreach($j->data as $v) {
  if ($v->type == $type) {
        //create variables
        $author_id     = $v->from->id;
        $original_id   = $v->id;
        $post_url      = getPostUrl($original_id, $author_id);
        //$description = stopWords($v->message);
        $description = $v->message;
        $pub_date = $v->created_time;
        //asign values to array keys
        $post['author_id']  = $author_id;
        $post['orginal_id'] = $original_id;
        $post['post_url']   = $post_url;
        $post['descritpion']= $description;
        $post['pub_date']   = $pub_date;
        //asign $post to the $posts array to create an array of $post(s)
        $posts[] = $post;

    }
}   
    return $posts;
}
```

I think this might help accomplish what you want.

the following code is the reference used. It is from the examples from the Array section in the PHP manual.

```
<?php
// This:
$a = array( 'color' => 'red',
            'taste' => 'sweet',
            'shape' => 'round',
            'name'  => 'apple',
            4        // key will be 0
          );

$b = array('a', 'b', 'c');

// . . .is completely equivalent with this:
$a = array();
$a['color'] = 'red';
$a['taste'] = 'sweet';
$a['shape'] = 'round';
$a['name']  = 'apple';
$a[]        = 4;        // key will be 0

$b = array();
$b[] = 'a';
$b[] = 'b';
$b[] = 'c';

// After the above code is executed, $a will be the array
// array('color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'sweet', 'shape' => 'round', 
// 'name' => 'apple', 0 => 4), and $b will be the array 
// array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c'), or simply array('a', 'b', 'c').
?>
```

Comment: It works if I strip [] from the variable $post. But if I do so, it will return only one value..and not all the values from the foreach as it is supposed to do... How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Like Eineki says you're trying to access an element of the array that doesn't exists. If you do a var_dump on the $post variable like this:

```
var_dump($post);
```

You should see that the $post array is actually a numerical array starting at [0] and each item includes a sub-array containing your data.

What you've created is a two dimensional array, an array of arrays, one array for each item in your $j->data array.

You can iterate through the array like this:

```
foreach ($post as $key => $value)
{
    var_dump($value);
    var_dump($value['author_id'];
}
```